# Possiblity using Kafka-Connector get Data from Python-Opcua-Client to Kafka-topic

Tags: apache-kafka, opc-ua

what have is a `python opcua client`.
 `datachange_notification(self, node, val, data)` will be performed as part of `python opcua client`whenever new data is arrived by `client`, see the script below, does it possible to send the arrived data(in this context is `val`) to kafka-topic.

```py
    def datachange_notification(self, node, val, data):
        saveData = save_file.Savefile()
        #save data locally when data arrived according to the nodeid=2
        if str(node) == "Node(NumericNodeId(ns=2;i=2))":
            if val != None and val != 0:
                print("Python: New data change event", node, val)
                saveData.saveBlockByClient(val)
        #save data locally when data arrived according to the nodeid=3
        if str(node) == "Node(NumericNodeId(ns=2;i=3))":
            if val != None and val != 0:
                print("Python: New data change event", node, val)
                saveData.saveSourceByValidator(str(val))
```

Comment: Note: library is in maintenance mode https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/python-opcua

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible? Sure.

Import a Kafka library and new up a Producer instance then send a message

If you use the AsyncIO client mentioned in the comments, I'd suggest researching aiokafka python library

Comment: the stream api is written in `official-java-kafka`. I plan to produce messages to topics with `python-kafka` and consume it with `java-kafka`. But if I do this, I have to import 2 kafka-libraries, so is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Faust is a Python native Kafka Streams-like library. But that's kinda the point of Kafka. Libraries exist in many languages and microservices are all the rage

Answer (score 0):

Please try if it works for kafka-python package-

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer

class KafkaOpcUaSubHandler(object): 
    def __init__(self):
        self.msg={}

    def connect_kafka(self, server, port):
        kafka_producer = KafkaProducer(
                bootstrap_server ='{}:{}'.format(server, port),
                retries=0, batch_size=0, compression_type=None
            )


    def kafka_message_producer(self, kafka_topic, msg):
        kafka_producer = self.connect_kafka(kafka_server, kafka_port)
        your_kafka_message = kafka_producer
                             .send(kafka_topic, json.dumps(msg, default=str)
                             .encode('utf-8'))
        kafka_producer.flush()


    def datachange_notification(self, node, val, data):
       self.your_function(node, val, self.msg, data)

    def your_function(self, node, val, msg, data):
        payload = []
        payload = [val, str(data.monitored_item.Value.SourceTimestamp)]
        self.kafka_message_producer(kafka_topic, payload)
```